# Debug Windows 10 Mobile Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, responsive-design, windows-10, remote-debugging

I was using 'Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer' (Debug Menu > Other Debug Targets > Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer) when I had Windows Phone on phone, but now I have Windows 10 installed on phone. How to use this feature on Windows 10 phone, where IE is not installed?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this feature is available yet for Edge mobile. It's recommended to use your Windows 10 PC Edge Browser developer tools plus emulator for debugging, since Edge on Windows 10 PC uses the same rendering engine.

More details at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/how-can-i-test-and-debug-microsoft-edge/

You can also use Vorlon.JS to test JavaScript code while it's running on a phone http://vorlonjs.com/

Comment: Which is totally useless because despite using "the same engine", Edge for mobile devices is a completely different version.